# jQuery multiple attribute selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find

I have this string

```
$html = "`<li class="A" test_id=".0.1.$111">
...
<li class="A" test_id=".0.2.$222">`"
```

and I want to get with jQuery the contents of the class A with test_id=".0.1.$111"

I am trying this but it doesn't work

```
$(html).find("class[value='A'],test_id[value='.0.1.$111']");
```

Does anyone know what is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using PHP? if so your `.0.1.$111` value will be return a PHP error because variable names can't start with a numeric character: `$111` is not good; `$_111` is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect for the attribute selectors, you don't need `value=`. Also there is a specific syntax for selecting by class: `.`. Try this:

```
$(html).find(".A[test_id='.0.1.$111']");
```

Note that adding non-standard attributes to your HTML is invalid, you should prefix them with `data-`:

```
$html = '<li class="A" data-test-id=".0.1.$111"><li class="A" data-test-id=".0.2.$222">';
var $li = $(html).find(".A[data-test-id='.0.1.$111']");
```

You can also use `filter()`:

```
$(html).find('.A').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('test-id') == '.0.1.$111';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.A[test_id=".0.1.$111"]').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="A" test_id=".0.1.$111">test</li>
<li class="A" test_id=".0.2.$222">test</li>
</ul>
```